# Can I inject services from MVC service layer to Blazor components?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I am building a MVC multitenant .NET 6 app and I need to use a Blazor calendar component in one of the views. I call it with this:

```
@(await Html.RenderComponentAsync<Scheduler>(RenderMode.ServerPrerendered, new {tenantId = Model.TenantId}))
```

passing TenantId into it.

I inject couple of services at the top of razor page:

```
@inject IAccountService accountService
@inject ITenantService tenantService
```

And then just use them in the methods in `@code{}`

Now, this is a regular MVC app, normally I'd use partials and ajax calls to controllers to load data dynamically. With Blazor, I figured I can inject services into razor pages (or code behind) and just call methods on my MVC services which will return data from the DB and potentially saving of the data will also go via MVC services.

Question is - should I be doing it? It's the simplest way in my opinion, I don't have to use AJAX, no need for JS, no need for implementing some new SQL connection especially  for one Blazor component, no need to create HTTPClients etc.

Or is it totally wrong, and I should somehow call controllers from code behind via API calls?

Comment: There's nothing inherently wrong with this, but do watch your DI Scopes. Your calendar lives as long as that page is open.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Thanks, I am mostly concerned about it being against the pattern and feels like mixing the service layer with views(?). An instance of Calendar/Scheduler will only live on one page/view so that's fine.

Answer (score 0):

Usually it can be done, only don't forget to add service to program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor();
```

and need add endpoint to it:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
    endpoints.MapControllers();

});
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. I know it can be done, I'm doing it. The question is, is it breaking pronciples/pattern as I have a regular MVC app with views and partials, and suddenly there is one view with a blazer component which in code behind is calling services that access DB to save/fetch data. Is that a correct way of doing it ?

Comment: Usually we don't do it in that way, but in MVC app using a blazor component is available, it's not common but it can be done.